# Get Date Difference Between Two Rows from SQL Resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I tried the method below to get the date difference between two from a SQL result set. I looked up google but no luck so I created the script below to accomplish the same. Hope it helps.

```
--- Query to get date difference between two rows 

declare @table table (olddate datetime, newdate datetime)
create table #table (olddate datetime, newdate datetime)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 

  SELECT  CONVERT(date,[utl_recycle_date] ) as RecycleDate
  FROM XYZ
  WHERE account_number = '6900' AND match_status = 'F' 
  AND [utl_recycle_date] IS NOT NULL
  AND [utl_recycle_date] > '11/01/2018'
  GROUP BY DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(date,[utl_recycle_date] ), CONVERT(date, GETDATE())),CONVERT(date,[utl_recycle_date] )
  ORDER BY 1

DECLARE @RecycleDate datetime 
DECLARE @NewDate datetime 

OPEN db_cursor 

FETCH next FROM db_cursor INTO @RecycleDate 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
  BEGIN 

      FETCH next FROM db_cursor INTO @NewDate

      insert INTO #table (olddate, newdate) values (cast(@RecycleDate as date), cast(@NewDate as date))
      set @RecycleDate = @NewDate

  END 

CLOSE db_cursor 

DEALLOCATE db_cursor 

select 
olddate, newdate,
CASE 
  WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, olddate, newdate) = 0 THEN 1 
  WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, olddate, newdate) > 0 THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, olddate, newdate)
  END AS RecyclerFrequency  

FROM #table

drop table #table
```

Comment: The answer you provided to your own question should actually be placed in the question itself.

Comment: @xhulk . . . Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

```
--- Query to get date difference between two rows 

declare @table table (olddate datetime, newdate datetime)
create table #table (olddate datetime, newdate datetime)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 

  SELECT  CONVERT(date,[utl_recycle_date] ) as RecycleDate
  FROM XYZ
  WHERE account_number = '6900' AND match_status = 'F' 
  AND [utl_recycle_date] IS NOT NULL
  AND [utl_recycle_date] > '11/01/2018'
  GROUP BY DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(date,[utl_recycle_date] ), CONVERT(date, GETDATE())),CONVERT(date,[utl_recycle_date] )
  ORDER BY 1

DECLARE @RecycleDate datetime 
DECLARE @NewDate datetime 

OPEN db_cursor 

FETCH next FROM db_cursor INTO @RecycleDate 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
  BEGIN 

      FETCH next FROM db_cursor INTO @NewDate

      insert INTO #table (olddate, newdate) values (cast(@RecycleDate as date), cast(@NewDate as date))
      set @RecycleDate = @NewDate

  END 

CLOSE db_cursor 

DEALLOCATE db_cursor 

select 
olddate, newdate,
CASE 
  WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, olddate, newdate) = 0 THEN 1 
  WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, olddate, newdate) > 0 THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, olddate, newdate)
  END AS RecyclerFrequency  

FROM #table

drop table #table
```